# Finding out the public IP of a VMSS instance from within that instance (per-instance public IP VMSS)

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-vm-scale-set

I’ve created a VMSS in Azure with per-instance public IPs described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-networking#creating-a-scale-set-with-public-ip-per-virtual-machine. I need a per-instance IP public IP configuration so that every individual instance is independently available from the outside.

Since there is apparently no way to specify a sku for such IPs (full format is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/virtualmachinescalesets#virtualmachinescalesetpublicipaddressconfigurationproperties-object), all IPs are always Standard. I can query public IPs as they are being created by VMSS, they are indeed Standard.

Metadata service (that I planned to use to get the IP from within the instance) only returns Basic public IPs (as stated here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/public-ip-addresses#standard).

How do I get the instance’s public IP *from within the instance* short of pinging a random 3rd party web site that returns the caller’s IP or talking to ARM from the instance?

Answer (score 0):

After my validation, you can get the instance’s public IP from within the instance refer to [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/instance-metadata-service?tabs=windows#sample-6-retrieve-public-ip-address). This also works to get the basic public IP from Azure VM.

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{"Metadata"="true"} -Method GET  -Uri "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance/network/interface/0/ipv4/ipAddress/0/publicIpAddress?api-version=2017-08-01&format=text" | ConvertTo-Json
```

[image]

I create the VMSS with public IP in ARM template like this:

```
                                            "publicIPAddressconfiguration": {
                                                "name": "publicip",
                                                "properties": {
                                                "idleTimeoutInMinutes": 10,
                                                "dnsSettings": {
                                                    "domainNameLabel": "[parameters('vmssName')]"
                                                }
                                                }
                                            }
```